# How to start using MQTT Paho JavaScript client?

Tags: javascript, mqtt

Hello esteemed everyone,

I am very new to JavaScript, and I was trying to start using the JavaScript client for MQTT. I have already checked [their example](https://eclipse.org/paho/clients/js/) that they have online, however, I still don't know how to start to make it work. I mean, how do I import the JavaScript client into my code? Also, I have tried the example through the console, but I got the following error and I don't know how to fix it.

```
VM440:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: Paho is not defined
    at <anonymous>:2:14
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:145:167)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:137:25)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:118:14)
```

If you also have suggestions and recommendations for where I can start I would be thankful because I haven't been able to find any decent results.

Comment: include it to clientside app using <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/master/src/mqttws31.js"></script>   in case of NodeJS You'll look for another module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt

Comment: I tried it but I got this error `Refused to execute script from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/master/src/mqttws31.js' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.`

Comment: See "'text/plain' is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled" - it means, You've to find workaround. for example download it to local folder, and include it in script tags

Comment: How about making it work in the console? I have already been able to include it into the code, but I am getting errors when I am trying to connect to `http://test.mosquitto.org/` even though it supports web sockets. This is the error: `mqttws31-min.js:36 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'WebSocket': The URL 'ws://[http://test.mosquitto.org/]:8000/mqtt' is invalid.`

Comment: ohhh... ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt   should be enough.

Comment: check this example: http://test.mosquitto.org/gauge/   view source code of it, copy it and modify to suit all Your needs

Comment: Thanks man, this helped me a lot. I believe it will be helpful if you put all that in an answer that will help others who will check this question later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As num8er has indicated in the comments:

> ws://test.mosquitto.org:8080/mqtt should be enough